# Why does my python run in vscode terminal but not vscode code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I keep getting syntax error when using `print(f"Addition: {num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}")` in my code.

[image: python input]

[image: python output]

The code also doesn't run when I double click and select 'Run python file in terminal' but it runs when I double click and select 'Run selection/line in Python terminal'.

[image: terminal output]

I have the latest python installed through homebrew.

Comment: You are only allowed to write comments in python code with '#'.  In your visual studio code you have 2 lines that are actually comments and doesn't start with '#'. Also remember that when you share code in stackoverflow, you must generally give it as text format. Edit: giving string without declaration as you did twice may not be the issue

Comment: For the record, when you post a question on StackOverflow, it is better to copy/paste the code as text instead of a screenshot. It helps people help you better.

Comment: Add `import sys` and `print(sys.version_info)` to your code, and rerun it within VSCode. I suspect you'll find it's not using the version of Python you expect (probably some older version that shipped with VSCode or the OS, rather than the newer version you installed through homebrew). Your code is syntactically valid in 3.6+, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was running in some ancient copy that pre-dates f-strings.

Comment: i added import sys and print(sys.version_info) and i got this: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=18, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: @1suleystack: Yep, that's the issue. VSCode is using ancient Python (2.7.18), long before f-strings were a thing. I don't know off-hand how you would configure it to default to some other version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like f-string is introduced from Python 3.6.

Therefore, in order to solve this problem, you need to update to Python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: If you check up ^^^ you can see that the vscode is running 3.10.6 but somehow its still not working.